# How to replace string with an element using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I replace a string with an XML element using XSLT 1.0?

Source:

```
<body>This has a keyword and may have another keyword</body>
```

Desired output:

```
<body>This has a <kw>keyword</kw> and may have another <kw>keyword</kw></body>
```

I have the following template but it only supports replacing the string with text.

```
<xsl:template name="replace-string">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace"/>
    <xsl:param name="with"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$with"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Any tips would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you already have, it looks like all that is missing is <xsl:element name="keyword"/> And if the element name is dynamic, use <xsl:element name="{XP}"/> where XP is an XPath expression.

Comment: How would I do multiple replacements in the same text? If I store the results in a variable they seem to get lost.

Comment: The question is a bit vague. Please provide your XML and XSLT together with the desired output.